Existing files on directory are not being polled/process when application restarts
I'm using spring integration xml. I have a file inbound channel adapter with a poller of fixed-rate=1000. I'm also using AcceptFileOnlyOnce filter and taskExecutor with multiple threads.
My directory is /apps/emailService/input. Let's say there's 10k files in that directory and I restart my application. It will just start and not do anything to the current existing files. Sometimes even incoming files are not processed if there's already files in the current directory.
Some thoughts I have

directory="/apps/emailService/input", I'm not using the prefix file: and only giving it the directory location. Could this be the cause? Would directory="file:/apps/emailService/input" fix it?
Is there some attribute that I need to enable for this issue that might be disabled by default?
I think I might have to add scan-each-poll=true but will this cause any issues with AcceptFileOnlyOnce or cause any other issues since it's false by default? Is poll rate 1000 still fine if I make this true since I'm not sure how much of a performance impact it will cause.


We need to know more about your configuration. The AcceptOnceFileListFilter is in-memory, so upon restart it is going to be cleared and all the files in the directory will be processed again. fixed-rate means to start a new polling cycle just after a start of the previous one. The fixed-delay calculates the next scheduling time after the finish of the previous one. This is more even distribution. The scan-each-poll might really cause performance bottleneck. The directory is scanned for all the file on a first receive call when no files in memory already.

Turn on DEBUG login level for the org.springframework.integration to observe what is going on when you start your application and how interaction with that directory happens. "10k files" really may take some time to be scanned into the memory.

hmm so I think the problem might be this. So you're saying even though my max-message-per-poll is let's say like 10 and I have 10k files in the directory. It has to cache all 10k files before it starts processing 10 messages per 1000 fixed rate polling cycle? Thus, scan-each-poll won't resolve this issue?

Also, what's the most efficient way to clear the cache of AcceptOnceFileListFilter daily without restarting? If I use LastModifiedFileListFilter and set the value to 24 hours. That will essentially remove the previous day cache right?
Also, what about the scenario if it's removing the previous day cache WHILE files are still being processed currently. Will there be some edge case thing for this scenario?

The understanding for polling behavior is correct. No, nothing is removed from that AcceptOnceFileListFilter. It might not be a bad idea to have some hook on that class like clearCache(Predicate<F> filePredicate). Meanwhile you can think about using FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter which can use an external DB when you would have a control for those processed entries.

Can you do payload.delete() AND AcceptOnceFileListFilter.remove(file) in after commit? Also, do we need to add channel attribute if there's no flow after that?
<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="mySyncFactory">   <int:after-commit channel="nullChannel" /> </int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

Yes, if you remove an original file, then indeed you can remove it from the filter as well. No, you don't need to specify that <int:after-commit channel="nullChannel" />.

<int:after-commit expression="payload.delete() && @acceptOnceFileListFilter.remove("/apps/emailService/input/ + headers['file_name']")
Is it something like that? Can you please provide a reference. I saw someone use acceptoncefilelistilter.remove in another stackoverflow post, but couldn't find it.

The SpEL expression is similar to Java code. So, that && is treated as a boolean and operator. I suggest you to put the logic into static method and call it from the SpEL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/expressions/language-ref/types.html

Are you saying to put it in a method because it's not possible to do both in the after commit expression without it? Is this how to do it public static AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File> fileFilter = new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>(); public static void clearCache(String fullFilePath) {File file = new File(FullFilePath); file.delete(); fileFilter.remove(file);} then in spring integration xml after-commit expression="#{testClass.clearCache(headers['fullNamePath'])}"

Actually thought of something. I keep the payload.delete() in after-commit expression and I change the channel=toServiceActivator. In the serviceactivator I just call AcceptOnceFileListFilter.remove() method. lmk which way you think is the best one.

I think I agreed with such an approach.

hmm I tried the spel way but was getting exceptions, so I did service activator way. I let after-commit expression=payload.delete() and made a new channel for a serviceactivator for the remove method. I tried using the remove method inside a if statement and It goes to the else statement. I tried just the filename.txt and path/to/file/filename.txt. Do you know what's wrong or how to check what's inside the acceptOnceFile hashset?

Ok nvm got it to work after reimporting project (the spel expression with no channel way) I passed in expression=T(class).method(payload) and public static void method(@Payload File file){file filter.remove(file)} but I don't think it's doing anything.

You can put break point into your method to investigate. On the other hand it feels like we have hijacked this thread and such a file removal subject deserves its own SO question.
